# What's the L in "open ( L , ">$logfile" )"?

Tags: perl

Can somebody explain to me what's the "L" in the code below ?

```
open ( L , ">$logfile" )
    or die "Can't create logfile \"$logfile\": $!\n" ;
print L "CMD: $cmd\n" , "=" x 78 , "\n" ;
close L ;
```

Open as it's a common word ("open"), it's more difficult to search for it.

This code is part of a script that logs ssh sessions. You can get the whole code here: http://pastebin.com/ZZbBj4tU

My actual problem is that when I try to run this script I get a "file not found" error in this part of the code. What I think is that it's trying to open an existing log when it should create the file first. But in order to fix this I need to understand what this L does first.

Comment: That's not bash, that's Perl: look at the top line of your script which is a 'shebang' to run this script using Perl. It's a file handle / stream identifier which you can declare with `local` or not declare at all.

Comment: oh my mistake... should have looked at the first line of the script. Sorry.

Comment: Syntax is ok, old two argument open.  The problem may be what the system is saying - it can't create the file, possibly because the path does not exist.

Comment: Yes... the problem was that I created the path in the wrong place :D But someone has found the below answer interesting, so I'll maintain this question. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`L` is the **freely chosen name of the file handle** that refers to file `$logfile`, which is being opened for writing (`>`);
`L` is then used in the later `print` and `close` calls to refer to the open file.

As others have noted, `open ( L , ">$logfile" )` is **outdated syntax** in two respects:

- Using a *bareword* such as `L` creates a *global* variable<sup>[1]</sup>, so the preferred approach nowadays is to **use a *local* variable**:

  - `open(my $fh, ...);  # local var. $fh receives the file handle`
  - Note that you then use the usual variable syntax - *with* prefix `$` - in later calls, e.g., `close $fh`.
- Specifying the file *mode* (`<` for reading, `>` for writing, ...) and the filename as a *combined, single* argument is deprecated; nowadays it is preferred to **specify the mode first, followed by the filename as a separate argument**:

  - `open(my $fh, '>', $logfile)`

<sup>[1] It's a globally defined symbol, but not a variable as such, because it can only be used in situations where a file handle is expected. You *cannot* refer to the `L` file handle as `$L` later.</sup>

---

Documentation links:

- [Tutorial on using `open()`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlopentut.html)
- [`open()` reference](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html)

Answer (score 2):

This is the perl [file handle](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html):

> Opens the file whose filename is given by EXPR, and associates it with FILEHANDLE.
>
> Simple examples to open a file for reading:

```
open(my $fh, "<", "input.txt") 
    or die "cannot open < input.txt: $!";
```

It seems your error is that you need to pass the arrow as the second argument and the file name as the third, not both in the same string.

Comment: This is no error, it is the old deprecated two-argument-version of `open`. And if the error message is "file not found" ... that cannot be from the lines the OP showed because the open has its own error message.